# Fastest String contain check in array for huge data in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, search, include

I need to check 2.000 string if string doesn't exist in array with 650.000 string elements. findIndex method with regex is finding the items but its too slow for response.I need fastest way to do that.I'm thinking if i can use regex in indexOf method i can reach my achieve because as i know indexOf method is the fastest way to search a string in an array.

```
//for example
let array1=["exa","val","har","esd","elf"]
let array2=["example","defvalue","harder","klein","rapper","doesnt"]

for (let index = 0; index < array1.length; index++) {
      if (array2.findIndex(value =>
         new RegExp(array1[index]).test(value)) == -1) {
        diffArray.push(muavinArray[index])
      }
    }
 //diffArray should be ["esd","elf"]
```

That's the working code but too much slower

Comment: Add a **sample** of both arrays please.

Comment: @Caner Ünver, could you provide a small example?

Comment: Are the elements in `array1` actually regular expression strings?  Or are they only plain strings you want to match?  And if the latter is it full-string matches or only partial?  Without data it's hard to tell, but I suspect you're trying to do way more work than needed for the problem.

Comment: you right guys sorry for adding example.I want to kind of sql like search "%value%"

Comment: Instead of `new RegExp(array1[index]).test(value))`, do `value.includes(array1[index])`

Comment: Have you tried something as simple as `const findUnused = (xs, ys) => xs .filter (x => !ys .find (y => y .includes (x)))`, which you could call like `findUnused (array1, array2)`?

Comment: Does all of `array1` consist of three-character strings?  That might allow for some optimizations.

Comment: @Ja͢ck that optimized well but i need much more faster

Comment: @ScottSauyet nope just wrote for example

Comment: @ScottSauyet i tried var diffArray = array1.filter(element1 => !array2.filter(element2 => element2.includes(element1)).length); But it is slower too at least Jack's solution.By the way i tried your solution too.Still jack's is better

Comment: @ScottSauyet your advice with findIndex instead of find much more better your originial solution

Comment: Which array has 2K elements, and which has 650K elements, the one with the smaller search strings or the one with the longer words?  That is, does the real `array1` have 2000 elements or 650000 elements?

Comment: Also, is this a one-time call, done occasionally, or do you need to do this often with one of the lists fixed and the other varying from call to call?

Comment: @ScottSauyet this is one-time call and Array1 has 2k elements and these are smaller search strings.Array2  has 650k elements and these are longer words.I'm searching Array1 elements in Array2 if that element element doesnt exist, pushing to the diffArray

Comment: Whatever technique you choose, you're going to have to do something on the order of 1.3 billion comparisons. What sort of speed are you looking to get out of it

Comment: @ScottSauyet i know but i just want to find best approach.For example if i dont need substring search indexOf is much better all of them.

Comment: I'm guessing that generating it would be too slow, but you might investigate making a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) out of `array2`.  That would allow a single pass through for each element of `array1`, instead of the continual searching.

Answer (score 0):

Filter `array1` and iterate `array2` with `Array.some()` to check if the current string is included in any string of `array2`. If it does, filter it out.

```js
const array1=["exa","val","har","esd","elf"]
const array2=["example","defvalue","harder","klein","rapper","doesnt"]

const result = array1.filter(s1 => 
  !array2.some(s2 => s2.includes(s1))
)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: it's working but slower than other solutions.I can already find the undetecteds but the important thing is performance.Thanks for advice

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if this will be much faster, a little faster, about the same, a little slower, or much slower than your original approach.  But there is some reason to think it might speed things up.  It is essentially a barebones [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) implementation.

```js
const simpleTrie = (words) => {
  const root = {}
  const addCharToNode = (node, char) => node [char] || (node[char] = {})
  const addChars = (node, [c = undefined, ...cs]) => 
    c == undefined ? node : addChars (addCharToNode (node, c), cs)
  const addSuffixes = (node, chars, [c = undefined, ...cs] = chars) =>
    c == undefined ? node : addChars(node, chars) && addSuffixes (node, cs)
  const findChars = (node, [c = undefined, ...cs]) =>
    c == undefined ? true : c in node ? findChars (node [c], cs) : false
  words .forEach (word => addSuffixes (root, word .split ('')))
  return (word) => findChars (root, word .split (''))
}

const findWord = simpleTrie (["example", "defvalue", "harder", "klein", "rapper", "doesnt"]);

const result = ["exa", "val", "har", "esd", "elf"] .filter (word => ! findWord (word))
 
console .log (result)
```

This is not a proper trie, as it finds any substrings of words added. This is as intended for the problem, though. It also doesn't allow for addition or removal of words from the trie; addition would be quite easy. Removal might be harder.  But again, that's not needed for the problem.

If it does seem like an improvment, you can probably squeeze a lot more performance out of it by replacing the elegant recursions with imperative loops.